# Use sed to remove matching patterns

Tags: sed

I have a .txt file I need to clean, both a set of strings with a consistent pattern, as well as a set of matching strings. What I mean is as follows:

I want to delete everything contained within brackets and followed by a colon, such as [example]:

And then I also want to delete all instances of the word, example

To accomplish the first part, I am using the following:

```
sed -i new 's/\[.*]://g' rp.txt
```

Any ideas what I need to add to achieve the second part, which would also delete any strings which match *?

Example input:

```
[John]: Hello Mary.
[Mary]: Hello John.
```

Desired output:

```
Hello .
Hello .
```

Using terminal in Mac.

Comment: it is extremely helpful for everybody to have a sample input and desired output. This way, the iterations to get the correct answer may be just one. Otherwise we will try to guess exactly what you mean and we may fail.

Comment: Like in `sed -r 's/\[.*]://g'`?

Comment: The sample input would be a file containing speech. So we have the string, "[name:]" everytime there is a new speaker, but also references to names within the file. We want to remove each instance of the strings, "[name:]", as well as any utterances of the names within the general text.

Comment: No, [edit] your question showing a proper format. You can also give a read to [ask] to learn how to present questions in a clear way.

Comment: Thanks, bufh, this resolved the first part. Now I need to remove all instances of any strings matching .*

Comment: You should have given the example up front; it makes things incredibly hard.  How is the code to know that the Mary on the first line needs to be deleted?  Does this mean we need two passes through the data, one to generate a list of candidate names from the `[Name]:` notations, and then generate the script to edit the file?  It would be one way to do it.  What should happen to a line `[John]: Hello Mary. What's going on with Peter Johnson?`?  Does the `John` in `Johnson` get zapped?

Comment: I wish I could downvote again: I asked repeatedly to have some sample input and desired output. Now that Jonathan Leffler offered a nice approach, you come with these requirements and invalidate the answer. See why you should read [ask]?

Comment: I note that the standard issue BSD `sed` on Mac OS X does not support the `-r` option.  You may be using GNU `sed` (which does support `-r`) because you installed it via one of the package managers, but if you've done that, you should say so.  There are major differences between the two versions — the `-r` option is one example (the behaviour of the `-i` option is another).  Also, do the `[Name]:` marks only appear at the start of a line?  Do you want the space(s) after the colon removed too?  Do you want spaces around the erased words removed too?  Please be precise!

Comment: [name]: Doesn't always appear at the start of a line, as sometimes the speech carries on for some length.

To answer your previous question, `John` would get zapped, not `Johnson`, unless `Johnson` appears somewhere else in brackets.

I don't mind about spaces. I am happy to leave them in.

Answer (score 2):

### An answer to the revised question

As noted in a comment, the revised scenario requires two passes over the data.  The first pass determines what needs to be edited.  The second pass applies the edits.  The solution includes `sort -u` to eliminate duplicate entries for a given word in square brackets, so 'the first' pass actually involves two `sed` scripts.

#### Script

```
sed -e '/\[/!d' \
    -e 's/]:[^][]*$/]:/' \
    -e 's/^[^[]*//' \
    -e 's/[^][]*\(\[[^]]*]\):/\1/g' \
    -e 's/\[//g' \
    -e 's/]/\n/g' data |
sort -u |
sed -e '/^[    ]*$/d' \
    -e h \
    -e 's%.*%s/\\[&]://%p' \
    -e g \
    -e 's%.*%s/\\<&\\>//%' |
sed -f - data
```

Note that this supplies the `sed` script as the standard input with the `-f -` option.  Not all versions of `sed` necessarily support this.
If yours doesn't, you'll have to capture the generated `sed` script in a temporary file, feed that file to `sed`, and then remove it.  Or use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).

#### Generated script

```
s/\[John]://
s/\<John\>//
s/\[Mary]://
s/\<Mary\>//
s/\[Name]://
s/\<Name\>//
s/\[like]://
s/\<like\>//
s/\[one]://
s/\<one\>//
s/\[something]://
s/\<something\>//
```

Note that this is using GNU `sed`, which supports both `\b…\b` and `\<…\>` to surround words (at least with `-r`; the `\<…\>` notation works without the `-r` option).  Mac OS X (BSD) `sed` does not support either, even under the `-E` option.

#### Sample data

```
[John]: Hello Mary.
[Mary]: Hello John.
[John]: Frank Johnson has a Name that is familiar.
[Mary]: A line [like]: this [one]: or [something]: similar should
be munged too.
[John]: A longer conversation with Mary that extends over several
lines which means that not all lines start with [Name]: but it
may actually be that when it occurs, [Name]: only actually
appears at the start of a line.
[Mary]: But it doesn't matter; we don't like this one, but
something similar should be OK, and should likely pacify the
Nameless ones, or someone acting all lonely on their behalf.
```

#### Sample output

```
 Hello .
 Hello .
 Frank Johnson has a  that is familiar.
 A line  this  or  similar should
be munged too.
 A longer conversation with  that extends over several
lines which means that not all lines start with  but it
may actually be that when it occurs,  only actually
appears at the start of a line.
 But it doesn't matter; we don't  this , but
 similar should be OK, and should likely pacify the
Nameless ones, or someone acting all lonely on their behalf.
```

It would be easy to add code to remove leading and trailing blanks and replace multiple blanks by singles.  A slightly more complex operation could remove blanks before punctuation such as comma or full stop (period).

### Original answer

> I want to delete everything contained within brackets and followed by a colon, such as `[example]:`
>
> And then I also want to delete all instances of the word, `example`.

Deleting what's contained within square brackets that are followed by a colon is tricky because the open square bracket is a metacharacter.  Should the output include the empty `[]:`?  That's what the question requests if read verbatim, but you probably don't want it.  So, you need one of:

```
-e 's/\[[^]]*]://g'        # Remove the square brackets and colon too
-e 's/\[[^]]*]:/[]:/g'     # Retain the square brackets and colon
```

The trick is that in a character class `[…]`, the `]` must be the first character after the `[` or `[^` at the start of the character class.  On its own in a regex, `]` is not a metacharacter; it becomes a metacharacter only after a `[`.

Note that both of these only match up to the first `]`.  If you use `.*` in place of `[^]]*`, you eliminate too much on:

```
a line [like]: this [one]: or [something]: similar.
```

Then, the other operation is simple unless you want to leave `examples` and `unexampled` untouched:

```
-e 's/example//g'      # Remove the string example when it appears
```

If you want to deal with word boundaries, you need to read the `sed` manual for your machine.  Different variants of `sed` have different options for marking word boundaries; some don't have any option for it.  When they do support it, `\<example\>` is one notation; `\bexample\b` is another.

Comment: sed -r 's/\[.*]://g' accomplishes the first part, removing everything I want. But I also want to delete every instance of *

The reason being, I am trying to delete the names of all speakers from a transcript, as well as references to their names within the text. I don't want to have to delete the names one by one, and rather match them to the strings contained in the brackets. There are no names contained in the text that do not appear in brackets at some point.

Comment: You need to use back-quotes around the command notation in a comment.  You need to show some example input (two or three lines) and the corresponding required output. Without that, no-one can help you much more.  Note my observation about `a line [like]: this [one]:`.  You may leigitimately decide that you never get two occurrences of `[…]:` on a single line, but you should have said that in the question too. Also, if you're using `-r`, you're presumably using GNU `sed`, probably on Linux.  BSD `sed` does not have that option (it uses `-E` instead). Identify the platform to get better answers.